# table does not alternate row color when filtered

Tags: microsoft-excel

I recently modified an excel sheet which required me to convert some tables on a tab to a range to remove an unnecessary column that was interfering when copying a range form one sheet to another.  When I went back to convert the ranges back to tables, the tables no longer alternate color when filtered.

What I mean by that is, when the table has no filter active, and all rows are visible, and the rows alternate between blue and white.  When I activate a filter now, I could have 2 or more rows with the same color next to each other.  Prior to the change, the colors would be alternate as if it was unfiltered.

My question is, what did I do wrong, and how can I fix it?

Edit: I am using Office Home and Business 2016

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  It may be helpful to identify the version of Excel you are using.  Please [edit] your post instead of adding information in a comment.

Comment: It may be that, in addition to the table format, the cells are formatted also. I think the cell format overrides the table format. Highlight the table and do the no fill command... Hope this helps

Comment: @gns100 you solved it! I don't think I can credit you with the points for the right answer unless you post it in the "Answer Question" section.  Thanks!

Comment: glad that was it! I copied my comment to an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy of my comment above:

It may be that, in addition to the table format, the cells are formatted also. I think the cell format overrides the table format. Highlight the table and do the no fill command... Hope this helps